# How to use Entity Framework with an Oracle database

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, entity-framework-4.1, oracle11g

I'm a starter in Oracle, I want to use Entity Framework to connect to my Oracle database.

I first installed Oracle 11g R2 and get [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-101290.html) and then I install NetManager and create new Service Name

[image]

Then, I go to Visual Studio and create a new model but wWhen I want to create a connection it gives me an error message.

[image]

Please help me. thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It had happened me once. In your Oracle home directory there must be two folder in directory C or `D:\app\user\product\11.2.0`:

Names of folder must be smth like that:

```
client_1   and    dbhome_1
```

There must be `tnsnames.ora` in  `\client_1\Network\Admin\Sample`. If not, create one. Then first of all  delete all texts in this file and copy this to that file:

```
orcl=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=172.16.77.31)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)))
```

Instead orcl you will write your data Source. Also for host and port number. And Service name.

It must work. If not copy `tnsnames.ora` and `listener.ora` to `\client_1\Network\Admin`.

And test it again.

Comment: @ FerhadJabiyev: in Sample folder have two files , sqlnet.ora and tnsnames.ora,Then I can put into one file? thanks

Comment: tnsnames.ora file and You must copy Listener.ora  file from dbhome_1\Network\Admin\Sample to client_1\Network\Admin\Sample

Comment: # tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: J:\app\MOHSEN\product\11.2.0\client_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

CMMorcl=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.135.23)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)))

Comment: @mohsen everything seems ok here. Have you copied Listener.ora from dbhome_1\Network\Admin\Sample to client_1\Network\Admin\Sample?

Comment: @mohsen ok. And have you copied all files from client_1\Network\Admin\Sample to client_1\Network\Admin?

Comment: is your service name "CMMS" coming in combobox  in ODP.NEt connection properties? or you write it by your hands?  @mohsen

Comment: I Write this, Combobox is empty

Comment: That is not no way to fix this problem?

Comment: I really want to help you. But I've resolved this issue in that way after so many explorations in google.

Comment: Should the service name automatically appears in combobox?